# How to get the task details where task_start_date older than 3 days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want all the records in mysqli query where task_start_date older than 3 days.

This is what I have tried using mysqli query:

```
$sql_task = "SELECT * FROM task where task_assignee='" .  $user_result['id']."' WHERE task_start_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)";
$result_task_dropdown = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_task);     
echo mysqli_error($conn);
$rows_task_dropdown=mysqli_num_rows($result_task_dropdown);             
$task_dr_result = mysqli_fetch_array($rows_task_dropdown,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This is my task table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `task_description` text NOT NULL,
  `task_assignee` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `task_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `task_due_date` date NOT NULL,
  `task_priority` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `task_status` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `task_remarks` text NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `delete_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: < curdate() - interval 3 day

Comment: Does `$user_result['id']` come from user input? If so, this code will have a SQL injection vulnerability. Look up parameter binding to solve that - luckily the MySQLi driver supports that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_task = "SELECT * FROM task where task_assignee='" .  $user_result['id']."' and task_start_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)";
```

Hope this will help you.